# MYPhpAdmin Search finds results, but show 0 results when using Replace

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am trying to run a replace query through MyPhpAdmin and it keeps returning 0 results, even though using the Search tab, I get 306 results.
Funny theing is I just ran the same query successfully on another table and it worked.
Here is the query

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` 
SET `meta_value` = REPLACE(`meta_value`, '%jwp-test/%' , '') 
WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%jwp-test/%'
```

even though in the search tab:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE  `meta_value` LIKE  '%jwp-test/%'
```

shows 306 results.
Just don't get where i am going wrong. 
any help appreciated.

Comment: Your searching 2 different things, why has the slash moved?

Comment: sorry copy paste error, edited to the correct string

Comment: Why not just write SET `meta_value` = NULL ?  You select criteria of WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%jwp-test/%' will pick the correct rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went to bed to think about it, read the comment above and this worked:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` 
SET `meta_value` = REPLACE(`meta_value`, 'jwp-test/' , '') 
WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%jwp-test/%'
```

So yes, it was removing the wildcards the replace, but leaving them in the where.

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE()` doesn't support wildcard searches (%), so you'll need to use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) (MySQL 8.0) or a more complex SQL statement.

Assuming you don't want to replace the value with NULL, something like this should work:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`
SET `meta_value` =  CONCAT( 
        SUBSTR( `meta_value`, 1, LOCATE( 'jwp-test/', `meta_value` ) -1 ), 
        SUBSTR( `meta_value`, LOCATE( 'jwp-test/', `meta_value` ) +9 ) 
        )
WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%jwp-test/%'
```

Comment: The same query worked on another table? i am trying to remove 'wp-test/' from a string, i dont want to null out the field